# you turned out -- what exactly does that mean?

Tags: meaning

From the movie [Road to Perdition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Perdition) (2002) starring Tom Hanks

Long story short, the main character played by Tom Hanks is a gangster who works for a rich mafiosi. He's a hitman—he kills people that the boss doesn't like. He's got a son, but the son doesn't know what his daddy really does for a living. And one day his son decides to find that out. So, basically one night he follows him out and sees how his dad and another gangster kill a man. But the dad catches him and everybody knows that his son saw what happened. The following is a short dialog between the daddy and the mafiosi:

> — How is Michael? ls he okay?
>   — I've spoken to him. He understands.
>   — That's tough seeing that for the first time. Well, **you turned out**. You can't protect them forever. If it wasn't this, it'd be something else. Natural law.

I'm not really sure what he means by *you turned out*.

Comment: I wanted to be a doctor when I was younger but, like the pancakes I made thus morning, that didn't turn out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure either. Based on the context, my best guess is that it is short for

*Well, you turned out (insert word here)*

where the word will describe how someone *turned out* (or: [developed in a particular way](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/turn-out)).

For example, *well you turned out (okay, despite the things you experienced in your childhood)*

I'm thinking the mafiosa just keeps it short to avoid any sentimentality. Or he doesn't want to stipulate *how* he thinks the person *turned out*.

I've never heard the phrase, with this meaning, before without some word such as 'okay', or even a negative one such as 'terrible'.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable explanation.  It's far more common to hear "you turned out OK", but I've heard it both ways lots of times (US English speaker).  Great movie BTW.